# How to document Azure Mobile Services Backend

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

Hi guys I have a question regarding Microsoft's Azure mobile services. I want to make documentation for the Azure Mobile Services Portal (the one on the url < fill name here >.azure-mobile.net), to let my friend know what the custom API is supposed to do when you make a request. I googled around for it but I did not found anything, and standard C# style documentations shows nothing. It must be able to document it, because on the site it tells me No Documentation available or sort of.

Comment: Any luck finding the solution to this "problem"? I'm struggling to document my APIs too and think that it shouldn't be that hard...

Comment: Nope mate. The answer below is just somewhat relevant, because the api management is basically for limiting the api calls and the documenting that side, which is then more public than the server alone, where you can connect only with master keys from azure

Comment: Also, I've tried doxygen type documentation in hope it will generate some docs, but no cigar so far...

Comment: Thanks for the info mate, why the hell do they show that info in the documentation page then? haha

Comment: no clue so far...but could be very nice to modify it for other coders in the team and don't rely on other documenting solutions like doxygen, or stuff like this

Comment: Hey man, looks like this link here has the solution to our problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819848/Master-the-Managed-Azure-Mobile-Services-Backend

Comment: yeah, looks like this should hit the head of the pin, will try, and if yes, then please make an answer mate, I'll give you the green tick mark, if it works, you've earned it :)

Comment: @Matheus it is correct, you should make it an answer instead of just comment ;)

Comment: Just added the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Showing the standard C# documentation on the help page is pretty straightforward.**

---

Basically for this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new user account.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">Object containing the basic information about the user.</param>
    /// <returns>User with the basic data and the JWT token.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="BusinessLogicException">
    /// Throws business exception if the user that is being created contains invalid data, such as invalid email, username and so on.
    /// </exception>
    public async Task<ResponseMessage<UserLogin>> Post(PostUserModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
```

To become this:

[image: API Help Page]

**All you need to do is:**

1. Right click your Mobile Services .NET project project (from within Visual Studio)
2. Go to Properties
3. Check the "XML documentation file" checkbox (image bellow)

[image: Properties Windows]

For more help page customization options, please follow this resource:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819848/Master-the-Managed-Azure-Mobile-Services-Backend

Comment: thank you Sire! Sorry for the delay, but yesterday was the day I've came across this again

Answer (score 0):

Try Azure API Management. It will create a developer portal for your users that will have documentation, test console, etc. and also management portal that provides analytic, quotas and much more. You can find more details [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/).